# phptopdf.php generate pdf not working

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm converting php to pdf with [phptopdf](http://phptopdf.com)  and I successfully generate pdf with that library but after generate pdf it's not working any pdf reader including any browser except Mozilla Firefox.

Generate pdf work only FF but I need to work atleast any pdf reader. I also tried online pdf reader but that's also not working.

I tried this http://phptopdf.com/examples/#generate_pdf_invoice snippet to generate pdf and also simple ones but none of working .

> Strange thing how generate pdf work only Mozilla Firefox why not any
>   others ?

```
<?php
 // INCLUDE THE phpToPDF.php FILE
require("phpToPDF.php"); 

// PUT YOUR HTML IN A VARIABLE
$my_html="<html lang=\"en\">
  <head>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <title>Sample Invoice</title>
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://phptopdf.com/bootstrap.css\">
    <style>
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
      body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
      font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class=\"container\">
      <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-xs-6\">
          <h1>
            <a href=\"http://phptopdf.com\">            
            Logo here
            </a>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class=\"col-xs-6 text-right\">
          <h1>INVOICE</h1>
          <h1><small>Invoice #001</small></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-xs-5\">
          <div class=\"panel panel-default\">
            <div class=\"panel-heading\">
              <h4>From: <a href=\"#\">Your Name</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class=\"panel-body\">
              <p>
                Address <br>
                details <br>
                more <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2 text-right\">
          <div class=\"panel panel-default\">
            <div class=\"panel-heading\">
              <h4>To : <a href=\"#\">Client Name</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class=\"panel-body\">
              <p>
                Address <br>
                details <br>
                more <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- / end client details section -->
      <table class=\"table table-bordered\">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h4>Service</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Description</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Hrs/Qty</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Rate/Price</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Sub Total</h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href=\"#\">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">-</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">$200.00</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">$200.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Template Design</td>
            <td><a href=\"#\">Details of project here</a></td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">10</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">75.00</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">$750.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href=\"#\">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">5</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">50.00</td>
            <td class=\"text-right\">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class=\"row text-right\">
        <div class=\"col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-8\">
          <p>
            <strong>
            Sub Total : <br>
            TAX : <br>
            Total : <br>
            </strong>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class=\"col-xs-2\">
          <strong>
          $1200.00 <br>
          N/A <br>
          $1200.00 <br>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-xs-5\">
          <div class=\"panel panel-info\">
            <div class=\"panel-heading\">
              <h4>Bank details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class=\"panel-body\">
              <p>Your Name</p>
              <p>Bank Name</p>
              <p>SWIFT : --------</p>
              <p>Account Number : --------</p>
              <p>IBAN : --------</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"col-xs-7\">
          <div class=\"span7\">
            <div class=\"panel panel-info\">
              <div class=\"panel-heading\">
                <h4>Contact Details</h4>
              </div>
              <div class=\"panel-body\">
                <p>
                  Email : you@example.com <br><br>
                  Mobile : -------- <br><br><br>
                </p>
                <h4>Payment should be made by Bank Transfer</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      This is a sample invoice.<br><br>
      In this example the css style is pulled from phptopdf.com/bootstrap.css
      You could also put all CSS in the header wrapped in <xmp> < style > </xmp> tags
    </div>
  </body>
</html>";

// SET YOUR PDF OPTIONS -- FOR ALL AVAILABLE OPTIONS, VISIT HERE:  http://phptopdf.com/documentation/
$pdf_options = array(
  "source_type" => 'html',
  "source" => $my_html,
  "action" => 'download',
  "file_name" => 'pdf_invoice.pdf');

// CALL THE phpToPDF FUNCTION WITH THE OPTIONS SET ABOVE
phptopdf($pdf_options);

?>
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys, I solved my problem.

Here is the two way I found that work.

1. useing external php as a form action then after form submit it work great but not work on same page if I used as a action link.
2. The better way saved that pdf first on your server after then fetch the link and after that download with that link.

example:

```
$pdf_options = array(
  "source_type" => 'html',
  "source" => $my_html,
  "action" => 'save',
  "save_directory" => 'wp-content/uploads/invoices/',
  "file_name" => $current_user->ID . '-' .$invoice['invoice_id'] . '.pdf');

// CALL THE phpToPDF FUNCTION WITH THE OPTIONS SET ABOVE
phptopdf($pdf_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DomPDF? I use it for all my projects. No issues..

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: Thanks for you hints and I already used that one before, that one not gonna solved my problem here you see you can't make pdf with desire marup and css with dompdf. It's support limited css.